# Entering Text into a editInPlace div using PageObject

Tags: ruby, watir-webdriver, page-object-gem

How can i enter a text into a Editinplace element as shown below using PageObject:-

### New Rule Name

as right now i have to click on the class="editInPlace" and sendkeys to it to enter some text into it

```
<div id="ruleContainer">
<div class="splitPanel basicInfo">
<div class="subPanel">
<div id="ruleName" class="editInPlace">New Rule Name</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Div elements have methods to click and send_keys. Are you saying that those methods are not sufficient? Examples of what you have tried and their result, would likely help to clarify the question and expectations.

Comment: Yes this is the error message iam getting "NoMethodError: undefined method `send_keys'  .                                               this is what i am trying to do                           div(:rule_name ,:id => 'ruleName')                                                                                           def name_rule                                       rule_name.send_keys "Test"                                          end

Comment: Which edit-in-place library are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Based on the example you provided you simply need to change the call to use the *_element generated method.  Try this:

```
def name_rule
  rule_name_element.send_keys "Test"
end
```

All element declarations will generate a method that has the pattern "name you provided"_element.  This method will return the actual underlying html element that you can make calls on.

Comment: Hi Jeff ..Thanks for the reply and as suggested i tried this  wait_until(10, 'Unable to send_keys'){rule_name_element.send_keys 'Test'}    and nothing happens on the element ...it proceeds to next step without doing anything ? not able to get any trace as the above step doesn't fail ....

Comment: tried this @browser.execute_script('$("#ruleName").text("testable")') and it works fine .....was wondering how can i customize it to PageObject